# How to delete duplicate music files where at least one version is .flac

Tags: command-line, bash, music

I had to consolidate several music directories, and have ended up with many duplicate files.  In instances where one is a .flac, I'd like to get rid of the dupes and keep the .flac. I'd like to only compare files that are in the same folder, as these represent albums, which is a useful way for me to organize my music.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10, with a bash shell.

I would appreciate your help with command line tools.  Thanks so much,

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer your question, I have some assumptions:
Say you have a directory like this

```
$ ls -1 myMusics
music1
music1.flac
music1.mp3
music2.mp3
music2b.mp3
music3.flac
music4.flac
music4.wav
music5b.flac
music6
music6.mp3
music6.wav
```

In the directory above, only `music1.flac` and `music4.flac` duplicates will be removed, because `music2.mp3`, `music2b.mp3`, `music3.flac` and `music5b.flac` have no duplicates to be removed, and although `music6` has duplicates, non of them have `.flac` extension. I've also assumed that there is no file such as `music1.backup.flac` in your directory. If such files exist, they will be treated as `music1.flac` duplicates ( if any ).

**Based on the assumptions**, you can do so:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ for i in `ls | egrep .flac$ | sed 's/\.flac$//'`; do rm "$i".!(flac);done 2>/dev/null
$ shopt -u extglob
```

Now let's see what the above commands do:

1. Second one lists all the files that have `.flac` extension at the end (`ls | egrep .flac$`),
2. then removes the `.flac` from the end of the name (`| sed 's/\.flac$//`),
3. then for each of the names that are result of two    previous steps, removes all of the files that has that name plus an extension,
4. except    for the ones which has `.flac` extension. `rm "$i".!(flac)` removes    every file that starts with `"$i"` and excludes the ones    that have    `.flac` extension. If you don't run `shopt -s extglob` (    that is, if    you don't enable `extglob` ), patterns like    `"$i"!(.flac)` will not    have any special meaning and bash searches    for the file name `"$i"!(.flac)` exactly. ( the name `"$i"` followed by `!` and then a `(` and so on. )
5. At the end, you can disable `extglob` using `shopt -u extglob`.

You can see the following about `extglob` in `man bash`:

> If  the  **extglob**  shell option is enabled using the **shopt builtin**, several extended
>   pattern matching operators are recognized.  In the following  description,  a  pattern-list  is  a list of one or more patterns separated by a |.  Composite patterns
>   may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> - ?(pattern-list)
>     Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
> - *(pattern-list)
>     Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
> - +(pattern-list)
>     Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
> - @(pattern-list)
>     Matches one of the given patterns
> - **!(pattern-list)
>
>     Matches anything except one of the given patterns**

Also, take a look at this SO question:
[How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm going to study this so I understand what you are teaching me.